# Visa for Thailand

Tags: visas, thailand, malaysia

Because it would have taken too long to get a visa from the Thai Embassy in Kathmandu, I left Nepal and flew to Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia. Would I be able to get a visa for Thailand in Kuala Lumpur? What documents do I need?

Comment: I feel as though no attempt was made to do any research for this question before asking it.

Comment: what kind of visa are you looking for?  how long are you staying? what is the nationality of your passport?  @jacob has a point, question is too open ended; debate-bait.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Royal Thai Embassy, Kuala Lumpur**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/th/services/72043-%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2-%7C-Visa.html)
>   206 Jalan Ampang
>
> **VISA INFORMATION**
>
> Visa applications can be made at the Royal Thai Embassy on working days from 09.30 to 11.30 hrs. In most cases, the visas can be collected on the next working day from 14.30 to 16.30 hrs.
>
> Visa application form can be downloaded [**HERE**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/contents/files/services-20170329-105614-806027.pdf).
>
> Visitors to Thailand require different types of visa for different purposes of visit. Please click on your applicable type of visa below for more details and the checklist of documents required.
>
> Please also note that TOURISTS from some countries are qualified for [**Tourist Visa Exemption**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/th/services/36314-Tourist-Visa-Exemption.html) and [**Visa on Arrival**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/th/services/36313-Visa-on-Arrival.html).
>
> Applicants from listed countries must reside in Malaysia and additional documents are required. Names of listed countries can be found [**HERE**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/contents/files/services-20170329-110629-261260.pdf).
>
> [**TOURIST VISA (TR)**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/contents/files/services-20170329-105808-985625.pdf)
>
> [**TOURIST VISA (TR) FOR APPLICANT FROM LISTED COUNTRY**](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/contents/files/services-20170329-105758-430188.pdf)